# What is the fundamental difference between evacuation and compaction in garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've read an extensive amount of documentation about the HotSpot GC of Java SE 6 and 7. When talking about strategies for obtaining contiguous regions of free memory, two 'competing' approaches are presented: that of Evacuation (usually applied on the young gen), where live objects are copied from 'from' to an empty 'to' and that of Compaction (fall-back of CMS), where live object are moved to one side inside a fragmented region to form a contiguous block of used an unused memory.

Both approaches are proportional to the size of the 'live set'. The difference is that evacuation requires x2 times space than the live set, where the compaction does not.

**Why do we need the Evacuation technique at all?** The amount of copying that needs to be done is the same, however it requires reservation of more heap size, and it does not allow for faster remapping of references.

True: the evacuation can be executed in parallel (where-as compaction cannot, or at least not as easily) but this trait is never mentioned and seems not that important (considering that remapping is much more expensive than moving).

Comment: Do you understand the benefits of having a dedicated, separate area exclusively for young objects? Assuming you do, how do you propose such an area is maintained when compacting?

Comment: Compaction, as well as copying- is done in an STW manner. In the absence of concurrency, the objects are simply pushed back one after the other- the operation of compaction is absolutely no different from evacuation. The only difference is the target region. Perhaps I do not understand your lead question...

Comment: To paraphrase my question: Suppose you have a nursery region of one MiB. After some mutator work, the nursery is full and is compacted. 500 KiB of objects survive and are promoted, now tightly packed in the first half of what used to be the nursery. Now how do you get back to a 1 MiB nursery?

Comment: @delnan Your point could be expanded into an answer. Then we would have three answers, each with its unique argument in favor of evacuation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm not comfortable with that because I honestly don't know if this is a fatal flaw. It's certainly a challenge, but *finding* another block shouldn't be too hard - I'm more concerned whether repeatedly moving the nursery will have further downsides (I would not be surprised if JIT-compiled code hardcodes the nusery address and size).

Comment: @delnan Have you checked out G1? There, the nursery regions are all around and fluctuating. Evacuation is still preferred due to other factors.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik See, that's why I didn't want to post an answer ;-) No, I haven't looked in depth at G1, though I vaguely recall some bullet points that match your description.

Comment: @delnan But I think your point stands for the "classic" generational GCs. In that framework there is no room for "flying" heap regions and it would be impossible to reclaim an empty Eden without copying.

Comment: @delnan, just to make sure we share the same conceptual domain, does 'nursery' mean 'young gen'?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, can you please elaborate as to how do I oversimplify compcation?

Comment: @Vitaliy Yes. More specifically, the nursery is the *memory region* for young objects, not those objects themselves.

Comment: Nursery is the Eden Space, whereas the Young Gen additionally involves two Survivor spaces.

Comment: @delnan, so regarding your question, the young gen fills up, there is nothing special about that. At some point the GC may decide to promote all objects from there, but note that if I am not copying but compacting, I have more space from the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

One big problem is that with "evacuation" the vacated space is, indeed vacant, while with "compaction" some other object Y may be moved into the space where object X was.  This makes it a lot harder to correct pointers, since one can't simply use the fact that a pointer points to an invalid location to clue the code that it needs to be updated.  And one can't store the "forwarding pointer" in the "invalid" location.

This makes GC much less concurrent -- the app must be in "GC freeze" for a longer period of time.

Comment: Would forwarding pointers really be used by HotSpot? Doesn't that complicate the code at each site of OOP dereferencing?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I don't know what methods HotSpot currently uses.  But certainly the original Sun scheme used forwarding pointers, and I had the impression that they continued using forwarding pointers into at least the early HotSpot implementations.  But the net/net is that if one uses a copying collector and wants to have any degree of GC concurrency, some sort of reference guard is required -- I can't imagine that HotSpot isn't using one.

Comment: And also this: although point forwarding may increase performance its seems that is is not as significant in the young gen due the the generational hypothesis. (small amount of 'incoming' pointers). The hotspot compiler maintains a remembered set as it is, so in case of moving an object- pointers can be fixed pretty quick. Which brings me back to my original question...

Answer (score 1):

Compaction is more suitable in cases where the number of reclaimable objects is expected to be low(e.g. Tenured generation) because after a few GC cycles the long living objects tend to occupy the lower portion of the heap and hence less work is needed to be done by the collector. If in such a case a copying collector is used that would perform very poorly because almost the same surviving objects from the previous cycles will need to be copied again and again from one location to the other.

Copying is suitable when the number of reclaimable objects is very high(e.g. Young generation) since very few surviving objects needs to be copied. If in such a case compaction is used that may perform poorly because the surviving objects may be scattered across the heap.

Other than that as mentioned in @Hot Licks answer Copying collector allows us to store a forwarding pointer which prevents from running into an infinite loop in case another object from the same "From" space refers to an already moved object.

Also, Compaction can not begin until all the live objects are identified, but live objects can be copied to the new location as soon as they are identified(using multiple threads).